# How to fix when built-in C++ header file will not compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, built-in

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 20.04. In the process I ended up with gcc 9.3.0. Now a program that used to compile fine will no longer compile. My program uses `<random>` and the compiler errors are with the built-in header file `opt_random.h`. Basically gcc complains that all the SSE intrinsics are missing, like:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/opt_random.h:70:15: error: ‘__m128i’ does not name a type
   70 |  static const __m128i __mask = _mm_set1_epi64x(__maskval);
```

When I do `gcc -dM -E -std=c++11 -x c++ -march=native - < /dev/null | grep SSE` I do see the `__SSE3__` macro is 1. So in `opt_random.h` it should be pulling in `<pmmintrin.h>` and have the intrinsics available.

But when trying to trace through the header files like

`echo '#include "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/opt_random.h"' | cpp -H -std=c++11 -x c++ -o /dev/null 2>&1`

the included header file `pmmintrin.h` is not showing up. Conversely when I do

`echo '#include <pmmintrin.h>' | cpp -H -std=c++11 -x c++ -o /dev/null 2>&1`

or

`echo '#include <random>' | cpp -H -std=c++11 -x c++ -o /dev/null 2>&1`

I get a tree of included header files just fine. With `opt_random.h` I don't. Looking at the code `__SSE3__` must be defined to have the intrinsics code included. But that should bring in `<pmmintrin.h>`, which should work.

I am not a C++ expert and I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

edit: The command (using `make VERBOSE=1`) is

`/usr/bin/c++  -Wall -g0 -O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/mypath/myfilename.cpp.o -c /home/mypath/myfilename.cpp`

Comment: Does the upgrade succeed?  We may consider reinstalling GCC.

Comment: Have you tried using g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling compiler, maybe something went wrong in the upgrade process

Comment: @ChrisMM `cpp`  is an alias of `g++`

Comment: That's an sse2 intrinsic. Maybe try adding -msse2 to the build args? (or later, depending on what CPU you are targeting)

Comment: can you supply a minimum code example that displays the same issue?

Comment: @robthebloke, the code in opt_random.h specifically checks __SSE3__. My build command includes -march=native and I checked, with that flag __SSE3__ is defined.